# Wind energy as a function of speed and temperature

Tags: energy, speed, applied-physics

My fellow windsurfers, most of whom have little knowledge of Physics, all agree that the force of the wind when sailing in the Northeast of Brazil, where the weather is warm, is much less than where we live in the Southern part of the country, where the weather is generally much colder.

Some claim that they have sailed in 40 knots wind on a 30⁰C day with a certain sail size which they would normaly use for sailing in 20 knots back home on a 10⁰C day.

Attempting to explain the reason, I found out that the power exerted on a sail is computed as 
$$ {P×V^3 ×A\over T}$$ 
where $P$ is the atmospheric pressure, $V$ is the wind velocity, $A$ is the sail area and $T$ is the temperature in Kelvin.  The formula should in fact be multiplied by a constant, but this is irrelevant for the present discussion.

Based on this, I told them that the temperature/wind velocity combination (30⁰C, 40 knots)  is equivalent to (10⁰C, 39.1 knots) but they refuse to accept that the difference in wind speed is so small!

Can anyone help me to:

> 1) Check/correct the above formula for computing wind power as a function of the various relevant variables.

The next question should perhaps go the the  Psychology & Neuroscience site of StackExchange, but alas, how can I

> 2) Convice my windsurfing pals that the difference is really not that big :-)

---

PS: Another explanation could be based on air humidity, since vapor is less dense than air, and hence a humid air is lighter than a dry one.  However I believe the difference of humidity in both places considered is not very big, so it does not justify the difference.

Comment: Do you have a source for your equation?

Comment: @AaronStevens, this is where I based my formula: http://drømstørre.dk/wp-content/wind/miller/windpower%20web/en/tour/wres/enrspeed.htm

Comment: How did you get to your final formula from this one? The reason I ask is because your equation doesn't given you power if you look at the units. Unless the constant you don't include also has units.

Comment: @AaronStevens $P$ is a typo for $\rho$. Density, not pressure.

Comment: I don't believe any sane person would go windsurfing in a 40kt wind. You would expect the height of the waves to be about 5 meters, for example. You wouldn't want to be in a small boat in that weather, let along on a windsurfing board.

Comment: @alephzero That still doesn't give units of power.

Comment: @AaronStevens, yes, the omitted constant has units!  The formula in the reference I gave, namely $(1/2)ρV³A$, indeed mentions density but, since I wanted to emphasize temperature, I used Clapeyron's law $PV=nRT$ (V = Volume, here), to deduce that the density is given by $ρ=n/V=P/(RT)$.  This results in the power being given by $(1/2) * P/(RT) * V³ * A$, so I bundled $1/(2R)$ into a constant, which I omitted, as it is irrelevant for my point.

Comment: @alephzero, 40 knots is pretty much the end of the sailable wind range for amateurs, but it is still doable with the appropriate size sail.  Professionals are known to exceed that windspeed by a lot (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV-sP5zOuws).  Five meter high waves on the other hand are peanuts for some sailors.  Given that a mast is about 4.30m high, try to estimate the wave height in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4znK_XdzUM.  One more point: In a windy day,  it is much safer to be on a windsurfer than in a small boat.